# Capturing groups in regex

Tags: regex, nginx

I have string `a/b/c/` and I want to get 3 groups (`a/`, `b/`, `c/`) by regex.

So, I can do this

```
^([^\/]+\/)([^\/]+\/)([^\/]+\/)$
```

but it is not very elegant.
I want to do something like this

```
^([^\/]+\/){3}$
```

but I get warning:

```
A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
```

So, I'm interested in the data, but I don't understand what I should change in the regex to get valid result.

[Test on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7JdS8a/2)

Small example for context (nginx config):

```
location ~* ^/([^/]+/)([^/]+/)([^/]+/)$ {
  rewrite (?i)^/([^/]+/)([^/]+/)([^/]+/)$ /$3$2$1 break;
}
```

in this case I rewrite url from `/a/b/c/` to `/c/b/a/`.

Comment: Do you only allow exactly 3 groups?

Comment: Do you want group 1,2 and 3 or only just 3 capturing groups? https://regex101.com/r/LeJSOv/1

Comment: Of course, I want to access each group ($1, $2, $3).

Comment: The number of groups is here for example. And yes, the coincidence must be complete, i.e. 3 groups.

Comment: @Grinnz Good tags edit, thank you .. I added nginx, perl their purpose

Answer (score 0):

There is really not much you can do to reduce the duplication in:

```
^([^\/]+\/)([^\/]+\/)([^\/]+\/)$
```

The warning is telling you that a repeated group such as `([^\/]+\/){3}` will only capture the last repeat. You might think that `([^\/]+\/){3}` is 3 groups, but it's only one group, because there is only one pair of parenthesis. That group is going to contain the last thing the quantifier matches, in this case `c/`.

So to have 3 groups, you must have 3 pairs of parenthesis.

If you *really* want to make the regex shorter, you can try:

```
[^\/]+\/
```

This will create 3 *matches* instead of groups, but you would have to check, using code, that:

- there are exactly three matches
- the end of each match is the start of the next match
- the first match starts at the start of the string
- the last match ends at the end of the string

in order to achieve the same effect as your original regex.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `^([^\/]+\/){3}$` repeats the group 3 times but group 1 will only contain the value of the last iteration. Perhaps [this page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#groupnumbers) at *The Returned Value for a Given Group is the Last One Captured* can be helpful.

If you want group 1, 2 and 3 you have to use 3 capturing groups in the pattern.

Not sure if this qualifies as more elegant, but perhaps is an option to get 3 separate matches using `\G` to get iterative matches and a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert that the pattern of not a forward slash followed by a `/` occurs 3 times:

```
(?:(?=^(?:[^/]+/){3}$)|\G(?!^))[^/]+/
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

    - `^(?:[^/]+/){3}$` Match 3 times a not a forward slash, then a `/`
  - `)` Close positive lookahead
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert postion at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[^/]+/` Match not a forward slash, then `/`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AZq9c9/1)